# What is the significance of Aemond's sapphire eye?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-the-dragon

In *House of the Dragon* episode 10 Lucerys Velaryon is sent to Storms End to deliver a message to Lord Borros Baratheon to ask for support of his mother's Rhaenyra claim to the throne.

While there, he is there he sees his uncle Aemond Targaryen who had previously lost an eye to Lucerys during a fight over Aemond's claiming of Vhagar.

The two exchange some heated words, and then Aemond tears off his eye patch to reveal a blue sapphire like stone in the place of his ruined eye.

[image]

We have no seen this eye or has it been mentioned in previous episodes, so what is the significance?

Comment: He replaced the eye he lost with this gem. I don't see what's so hard to understand about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply an [artificial eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocular_prosthesis). Historically they were [made of gold](https://ocularist.org/resources_faqs.asp/#howlongeyesbeenaround), but Aemond apparently chose a different precious material.
We haven't seen this sapphire before as in court he [preferred to cover it](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aemond_Targaryen#Appearance_and_Character):

> At the age of ten, Aemond lost his right eye during a fight with his
> nephew Lucerys Velaryon. Subsequently Aemond took to putting a
> sapphire in place of the missing eye. Aemond was also known to wear
> an eye patch over his sapphire eye at times, apparently when he was in
> open court and did not want to frighten noble ladies with his scars
> (such as when he was in the Round Hall of Storm's End with Borros
> Baratheon's wife and daughters).

Later edit: This already has a precedence in ASOIAF world with the legendary character [Symeon Star-Eyes](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Symeon_Star-Eyes):

> Symeon Star-Eyes is a legendary figure from the Age of Heroes who was
> blind. (...) According to legend, Symeon was a knight who lost both of
> his eyes. He replaced them by putting star sapphires in the empty
> sockets, or so the singers claim.

Answer (score 6):

[The other answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/118859/45378) is of course correct that this is just being used as an artificial eye. However, it's worth mentioning that the whole scene at Storm's End is almost perfectly accurate to the books. There are also only 2 instances of his eye being replaced with the sapphire in *Fire & Blood* and both are in this scene. I think it's safe to say that there is no significance here; just that, that is what he chose to go with:

> Thus it was not a raven who took flight for Storm’s End that day, but Vhagar, oldest and largest of the dragons of Westeros. On her back rode Prince Aemond Targaryen, with a sapphire in the place of his missing eye. “Your purpose is to win the hand of one of Lord Baratheon’s daughters,” his grandsire Ser Otto told him, before he flew. “Any of the four will do. Woo her and wed her, and Lord Borros will deliver the stormlands for your brother. Fail—”
>
> <sub>*Fire & Blood*, The Dying of the Dragons - The Blacks and the Greens</sub>

> But Prince Aemond drew his sword and said, “Hold, Strong. First pay the debt you owe me.” Then he tore off his eye patch and flung it to the floor, to show the sapphire beneath. “You have a knife, just as you did then. Put out your eye, and I will let you leave. One will serve. I would not blind you.”
>
> <sub>*Fire & Blood*, The Dying of the Dragons - A Son for a Son</sub>

It is worth noting though that Aegon does have a bit of a dramatic and extravagant flair so the choice of stone to go in the socket is likely mostly due to that.

The other reason is that he is there to woo one of the Baratheon daughters; a fancy stone could have come into play there should he have needed to. Better that than something gross or an empty socket and a sapphire does arguably look more like an eye than most other stones.

---

I will note though that I don't think the specific choice of stone has much reason to it except to look like an eye. Blue is neither the colour for the Hightowers or the Targaryens. It doesn't match their faction: the Greens.

Answer (score 1):

While we do not necessarily know if Aemond's trajectory will follow [*Fire & Blood*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_%26_Blood_(novel)), I would argue there is still symbolic significance to the choice/appearance of eye [stone] color.

One major deviation from any previous source material has been the reveal that some members of House Targaryen know and bare knowledge about the prophecy of "[The Prince that was Promised](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_prince_that_was_promised)" and the enemy from the north (aka: The White Walkers).

[image: catspaw]

Because of King Viserys, The prophecy has become one "reason" or point of contention for why *'A Dance of Dragons'* will occur, as he had passed the knowledge down earlier to his daughter Rhaenrya and on his deathbed, he perhaps unknowingly rattles off the name of the coming Aegon (The Prince who was Promised) to Alicent, who believes he is referring to their son Aegon II as opposed to Aegon IV (Jon Snow), who will save the Seven Kingdoms from this enemy in the North...

[image: NighTarg]

Aemond's eye color then matches the aesthetics of **The White Walkers** and/or their "wights" eyes; and by his acts in episode 1.10, he has now started the war by killing his cousin and his cousin's dragon, making him one of the bigger players in the series, and perhaps a "great enemy" beyond either his aunt/sister or his mother for reasons that are still unclear...

[image: dragonglass]

And while there is yet to be any "direct" correlation between the White Walkers & Aemond, it should be noted that the TV series adaption of *A Game of Thrones* changed the backstory of the [White Walkers](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/White_Walkers) from the books by revealing an untold origin story of the Night King, who was once human, but was turned into a White Walker by The Children of the Forest via magic with [DRAGONGLASS](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Dragonglass) during The Age of Heroes. It is possible that Aemond's eye-stone could relate this magic somehow (There is also The "White" Worm to consider), and/or the backstory of the White Walkers, but it also could just be an ongoing aesthetic theme that symbolizes his role in the series going forward being on par to The Night King as a formidable villain.